# How Connecting to a MySQL Database with caching_sha2_password mode with NetBeans?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, server, cryptography, connection

I want to connect to DataBase MySQL by registering a user who when authenticating is subject to cryptography. I use windows 10 and my **my.ini** file has the following property **default_authentication_plugin = caching_sha2_password**
I followed all the existing documentation about this plugin and although it does not say anything about netbeans, I have added the following properties:

```
# CLIENT SECTION
[mysql]
no beep
--ssl-mode = PREFERRED
-ssl-ca = ca.pem
--ssl-cert = client-cert.pem
--ssl-key = client-key.pem

# SERVER SECTION
[mysqld]
tls_version = TLSv1.2
--ssl-cipher = ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl-ca = ca.pem
ssl-cert = server-cert.pem
ssl-key = server-key.pem
```

However the result is the same, while following this tutorial [Connecting to a MySQL Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) in **"Starting the MySQL Server" step** I get the error **Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password**. All solutions found on the internet speak to change the property
**default_authentication_plugin = caching_sha2_password**
to
**default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password**

This even fixes the error, but the problem is that I want my database encrypted. My question is, how to do MySql connection with netbeans using **default_authentication_plugin = caching_sha2_password property**

The error **Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password** occur when i try connect after set properties window

[image]

[image]

or when i try start database after right-click on MySqL Server at localhost:3306 [cloud] (disconnected)

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you might be using an older version of the **MySQL Connector/J** driver. What version do you have? If it is < 8.0.9 see the release note **[Changes in MySQL Connector/J 8.0.9...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-9.html)** which states: _"Connector/J now supports the new caching_sha2_password authentication plugin, which is the default authentication plugin for MySQL 8.0.4 and later"_. In short, be sure to use recent versions of MySQL and Connector/J if you want to use caching_sha2_password. Update your post with the versions you use if appropriate.

Comment: My version is 8.0.13, is the last version. I want create an small program in model client-server. I think that to implement this programe i need MySql server, or MySQL Connector/J run as client-server?
I start read documentation, and MySQL connector/j need connect with MySQL server, i continue read thanks.

Comment: @skomisa i need my own certificates or the defaults certificates work fine?